# basic sql - how to pivot using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Very basic question

Right now my query is like

select table.a, table.b, table.c from table

```
A   B    C  

1   2    3
```

.

I need my output to be

```
NAME    ID
A       1
B       2
C       3
```

.

Is there a way that I can pivot my current output or query this table in a different way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need UNPIVOT:

```
select * from table1 unpivot (id for name in (a,b,c));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 'A' as name, (
    select A 
        from table1
        ) as ID
union all
Select 'B', (
    select B 
        from table1
    ) as ID
union all
Select 'C', (
    select C 
        from table1
    ) as ID
```